# Android: layoutParams.setMargins() changes size of view

Tags: android

I have a button that I want to change the margins of.
Here is my code:

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                 buttonParams.setMargins(r.getWidth() / 3 * 2, r.getHeight() * 5 / 7, 0, 0);
                 b.setWidth(r.getWidth() / 4);
                 b.setHeight(r.getWidth() / 8);
                 b.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
```

The size of b changes when I change the values in setMargins. Why is this the case and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its because you have

```
   b.setWidth(r.getWidth() / 4); 
   b.setHeight(r.getWidth() / 8);
```

before setting layout params

Remove setting width and height to **b** to not change its dimesions.

Cheers,
Sha